# Protractor web Driver update suddenly stopped working Error code: 135

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

I was looking through stack overflow but couldn't find anyone who had a similar situation as mine.

I am trying to open protractor webdriver from package.json using `npm run start` and I got the following error message (see below).

What is this? and how do I fix it?

```
[16:21:15] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:21:15] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[16:21:15] E/launcher - Error code: 135
[16:21:15] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
[16:21:15] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:238:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:399:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[16:21:15] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 135
npm ERR! LocatorTraining@ protractor: `protractor configurations.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 135
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the LocatorTraining@ protractor script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jacquelinegeorge/.npm/_logs/2018-11-08T16_21_15_711Z-debug.log
```

here is the package.json file as well for good measure

```
{
  "name": "LocatorTraining",

  "dependencies": {

"protractor":  "^5.4.1",
"jasmine-data-provider": "^2.2.0",
"protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter":"^0.0.7"



  },


  "scripts": {
    "webdriver-update": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-start": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "protractor": "./node_modules/.bin/protractor configurations.js",
    "SmokeTest": "./node_modules/.bin/protractor configurations.js  --suites Smoke",
    "RegressionTest": "./node_modules/.bin/protractor configurations.js  --suites Regression",

     "start": "npm run webdriver-update && npm run webdriver-start"

  }

}
```

Comment: what if you change `webdriver-update` to `prewebdriver-start` and then change `start` to `npm run webdriver-start`? Any difference?

Comment: What version of node are you running? I've seen a few issues around 8.12

Comment: @cnishina I am running 11.1.0.  I had 3 days of problems updating my old 7.2.0.  So ended up d using NVM (Node Version Manager) because.  11.1.0 If its not suitable, what should I do?  If I have to go down a  version how to I do that using node version manager?

Comment: @ tehbeardedone  thank you I will give that a try.  I will get back to you

Comment: I do not experience with node 11 either. I would try the LTS version of node which is 10.13.0.

Comment: @cnishina   How do I install 10.13.0 using NVM?  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you are using nvm, you should just be able to call `nvm install 10.13.0` then use it. `nvm use 10.13.0`

Comment: @cnishina  updated to 10.13.0 this morning and I got   `E/launcher - Error code: 135
[13:46:21] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
[13:46:21] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444`

Comment: This might mean that there's a Java process / server using port 4444. Check what ports are being used or what process / activities have started using that port. Then kill the process id.